# Errow swallowing in rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java

I  have `showExpenses()` method which cause `NullPointerExeption`. For some reason, my application is not crashing. Instead rxjava passing error to `subscribe()` method which I find pretty confusing. Is there a way to make app crash if exception is thrown outside of rxjava working thread?

```
 ExpensesByFolderRetrofitService service =
            RetrofitBuilder.createBuilderWithAuth()
                    .create(ExpensesByFolderRetrofitService.class);
    service.getFolderExpenses(folderId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(expensesResponse -> {
                if (expensesResponse == null) {
                    getViewState().showError();
                } else {
                    getViewState().showExpenses(expensesResponse);
                }
            }, error -> {
                getViewState().showError();
            });
```

Comment: If you want to make ti crash, just remove the `onError` block, or inside your `onError` block you can call `throw Exceptions.propagate(error);`

Comment: @GVillani82 I want it crash only if crash occurs outside of observable working thread. So if got any of network errors, I want them to be passed into `onError` but if would made illegal operation in successful case of `onSubscribe()` method I want it crash.

Comment: But are you using RxJava or RxJava 2?

Comment: I m using RxJava. I had removed the wrong tag.

Comment: Ok, then it makes sense, because in RxJava 2 the app will crash. But in RxJava 1 the throwable is thrown to the `onError`.

Comment: Is the above code running in a separate process from the `Application`? I can't think of another reason why an exception in `getViewState().showExpenses()` wouldn't crash your app.

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer I had checked that. If I setting breakpoint inside `showExpenses()` method it shows that main thread is paused. Also I'm successfully manipulating set of view from that method so it should be main thread.

Comment: Hmm, seems like something weird is going on here. Either the exception is not being thrown in the subscriber, or the code above is triggered inside another RX chain and the error is delivered to that chain's subscriber, or simply the built artifact is not reflecting the code and a `./gradlew clean` is required. I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Yes you would think the code you posted would crash the app, can you post some more code for context?

Answer (score 0):

rx assumes functional programming style where errors are handled as first-class values, with anything else handled by `onError`. However what you ask is possible.

I think your question can be rephrased to ask to re-throw exception if it occurs inside subscriber `onNext`. Thread considerations are irrelevant. That can be done as follows:

```
Observable
  .just(1)
  .subscribe(
    t -> {
      try {
      ....
      } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new OnErrorFailedException("Subscriber failed", e);
      }
    }, 
    error -> handleError(error)
  );
```

Exception can be wrapped in any exception from  `rx.exceptions.Exceptions.throwIfFatal`. `OnErrorFailedException` seems to me  to be the best choice considering, but keep in mind that this is somewhat non-idiomatic usage of rx and perhaps you want to remodel the processing so what all errors are handled explicitly.